# i want to open popup on single click in syncfusion ej2-react-schedule

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component

In reacjs syncfusion ej2-react-schedule i want to open custom popup on single click of scheduler is it possible? currently custom popup open on double click of cell

Answer (score 0):

Scheduler has cellClick callback. You can do whatever you want in this callback. For example:

```
 function onCellClick(args: CellClickEventArgs): void {
   scheduleObj.current!.openEditor(args, 'Add');
 }
```

If you ask in their community forum, you can get a much faster response, https://www.syncfusion.com/forums